# Error while run ng test after angular update form 8 to 9

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, angular8, angular9, angular-test

ERROR in ../node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/test.d.ts:831:34 - error TS1005: '?' expected.

831             : F extends abstract new (...args: any) => infer T
~~~
../node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/test.d.ts:832:17 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

[error screenshot aafter run ng test ss1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gFkh.png) 
[ss2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRzG7.png)

i want step to solve this error and run ng test and test hole project

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.